# Android Paging 3 : How to refresh whole data in the paging 3 and after update first item should be visible

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I have following scenario:

1. When I launched the activity I need to load some data.
2. The activity has refresh button which will load new data from the network. This will be a new list of data which will not match to the initial list.
3. Now suppose user has scrolled down to page 6 before hitting refresh button. Now when user hits refresh how to update the whole list and jumping to the position 0 first page.

I tried below steps but did not get any success:

1. Used InvalidatingPagingSourceFactory and invalidating it before calling adapter?.refresh()
2. Tried to set nextpage to 0 when calling adapter?.refresh() but this also did not work.

Everytime data gets updated but recyclerview position is maintained. Please help. I want my recyclerview to point to the first item whenever I fill new data.

Comment: Did you implement `PagingSource.getRefreshKey`?